# Windows iot device raspberry 2 usb composite device

Tags: win-universal-app, iot

We have `raspi` 2 windows `iot` device. I m trying to communicate from `raspi 2` to usb composite device.(could be serial, or usb). 
From windows universal application can succesffull communicate with `Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication`  lib.
But I don't want to use universal solution. Best way for my case to use `Windows IoT Core Console application`. I could't find any way to use(`Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication`)  communicate from core console application. Can I add this reference or do you have any other lib to use at 
console application.
Thank you for your time.